# Override @mui default theme spacing based on breakpoint

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I can overrider color but can't override spacing. I want to make spacing smaller globally for mobile phones

```js
const Styled = styled(Paper)(({ theme }) => ({
  spacing: 50,
  color: '#ff0099',
  [theme.breakpoints.down('md')]: {
    spacing: 30,
    color: '#9900ff',
  },
}))
```

Answer (score 0):

`spacing` is not a css property. it is a mui funciton.

https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/spacing/

Here I use `spacing` function to add padding:

```
const Styled = styled(Paper)(({ theme }) => ({
  padding: theme.spacing(2)
```

Comment: So, you want to override function and not css property then. Try to set spacing: 100px, in the theme config, it works as a property.

Comment: By the way, do you know that if you set padding: 2 there, it will be equal to theme.spacing(2)?

Comment: It is not overriding, it is using. instead of hardcoding the value of padding or any other property, one could use this function.
This:
`padding : theme.spacing(2); // ${8 * 2}px = '16px'`
is equivalent to:
`padding: 16px`
MUI uses a recommended 8px scaling factor by default.

Comment: You see I want to change that scaling factor on fly, not to add sx={{p: {md: theme.spacing(2), xs: theme.spacing(1)}}} everywhere. It would be great to reduce all of them by overriding that scale factor. Just like a color